# Problemas con login de Facebook

Tags: android, kotlin, facebook

Estoy tratando de cambiar de actividad una vez se hace *login* en *Facebook* desde mi aplicación.
No he podido lograr que cambie de *activity*. Una vez permito el acceso a *Facebook* , se sale de la aplicación.

Dejo una imagen de dónde mi aplicación se queda estancada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código.

```
class principio : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var LoginButton: LoginButton
    lateinit var callbackManager: CallbackManager
    lateinit var fotoPerfil: ImageView
    lateinit var Profile: Profile;

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principio)

        LoginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button)
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()

        LoginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
        fotoPerfil = findViewById(R.id.Bienvenida)

        // Login Facebook
        LoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
            override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult?) {
                Toast.makeText(this@principio,"se obtuvo  el resultado",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                saltarActividad()
            }

            override fun onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(this@principio,"se cancela",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            override fun onError(error: FacebookException?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        })
    }


    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        saltarActividad()
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }

    var tokenTracker: AccessTokenTracker = object : AccessTokenTracker() {
        override fun onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(oldAccessToken: AccessToken?, currentAccessToken: AccessToken?) {
            if (currentAccessToken == null) {
              saltarActividad()
                fotoPerfil.setImageResource(0)
                Toast.makeText(this@principio, "User Logget Out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            } else {
                loadUserProfile(currentAccessToken)

            }
        }
    }

    fun loadUserProfile(newAccesToken: AccessToken) {
        var parametros = Bundle()
        var Activity2 = saltarActividad()

        var GraphRequest: GraphRequest =
            GraphRequest.newMeRequest(newAccesToken, object : GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback {
                override fun onCompleted(`object`: JSONObject?, response: GraphResponse?) {
                    var first_name: String = `object`!!.getString("first_name")
                    var last_name: String = `object`.getString("last_name")
                    var email: String = `object`.getString("email")
                    var id: String = `object`.getString("id")
                    var image_url: String =
                        "https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "picture?type=normal"
                    
                    Toast.makeText(this@principio,"se quedo aqui",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Glide.with(this@principio).load(image_url).into(fotoPerfil)
                    fotoPerfil.buildDrawingCache()
                    var bitmap = fotoPerfil.drawingCache
                    Activity2.putExtra("first_name", first_name)
                    Activity2.putExtra("last_name", last_name)
                    Activity2.putExtra("email", email)
                    Activity2.putExtra("BitImage", bitmap)
                    startActivity(Activity2);
                }
        })
            
        parametros.putString("fields", "first_name,last_name,email,id")
        GraphRequest.parameters = parametros
        startActivity(Activity2);
        GraphRequest.executeAsync()
    }

    private fun saltarActividad(): Intent {
        var Activity2 = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        return Activity2
    }
}
```

He leido un poco que es en el apartado de

```
LoginButton.registerCallBackk{ override fun onSucces() }
```

pero he tratado de implementar el startAcitvity en ese apartado y no funciona.

¿Alguien podria ayudarme?

Comment: Si se sale de la aplicación lo más probable es que tengas un crash en la aplicación, sería de ayuda si añadieses el error que te está dando.

Comment: En el Logcat no aparece niun error, simplemente me indica que se finalizo bien el proceso :(